# Xamarin forms iOS app, Command button not firing when pressed

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tried everything I could find on the internet and still cannot get the event to fire.  My page contains 2 buttons as you can see which fire in the Simulator but not on my iphone. I have tried many different solutions found on the internet and the one I am showing here is the last one I attempted.

Here is the buttons defined in my view:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModel:EditViewModel}}, Path=UpdateMileage}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" IsEnabled="True" Text="Update" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextColor="Black" Margin="4"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModel:EditViewModel}}, Path=Cancel}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Cancel" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextColor="Black" Margin="4"/>
```

The viewModel code is as follows;

```
    public ICommand UpdateMileage
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public EditViewModel()
    {
        UpdateMileage = new Command(UpdateMileageData);

        MileageTableDefination mileage = new MileageTableDefination();
        mileage = Application.Current.Properties["MileageData"] as MileageTableDefination;
        SDate = Convert.ToDateTime(mileage.Date);
        EntMiles = mileage.Miles.ToString();
        EntGas = mileage.Gas.ToString();
        EntCost = mileage.Price.ToString();
        if (mileage.Note != null)
            EntNote = mileage.Note.ToString();
        EntId = mileage.Id;
    }

    public async void UpdateMileageData()
    {
        Analytics.TrackEvent("In UpdateMileageData Top ");
        int autoId = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties["autoId"]);
        //Analytics.TrackEvent("Mileage Data in Enter Mileage: AutoId " + autoId);
        error = false;
        IsVisibleLabel = false;

        if (EntMiles == "0" || EntMiles == null)
        {
            error = true;
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "Miles Driven Must Be Numeric";
        }
        else if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(EntMiles, @"^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$"))
        {
            error = true;
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "Miles Driven Must Be Numeric";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDecimal(EntMiles) > 1000)
        {
            error = true;
            //IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "Miles Driven Since Last Fillup";
        }
        if (EntGas == "0" || EntGas == null)
        {
            error = true;
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "Gas Used Must Be Numeric";
        }
        else if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(EntGas, @"^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$"))
        {
            error = true;
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "Gas Used Must Be Numeric";
        }
        if (EntCost == "0" || EntCost == null)
        {
            error = true;
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "Cost Must Be Numeric";
        }
        else if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(EntCost, @"^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$"))
        {
            error = true;
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "Cost Must Be Numeric";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDecimal(EntCost) > 300.00m)
        {
            error = true;
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "Cost Must Be Numeric And < $300";
        }
        Analytics.TrackEvent("In UpdateMileageData After If's Error = " + error);
        if (!error)
        {
            miles.Date = SDate.Date;
            miles.StrDate = SDate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            miles.Miles = Convert.ToDecimal(EntMiles);
            miles.Gas = Convert.ToDecimal(EntGas);
            miles.Id = EntId;
            miles.CarId = autoId;
            miles.MPG = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(EntMiles) / Convert.ToDecimal(EntGas), 3);
            miles.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(EntCost);
            miles.Note = EntNote;
            MileageItemRepository mir = new MileageItemRepository();
            var results = await mir.UpdateMileageAsync(miles);
            Analytics.TrackEvent("In UpdateMileageData Results = " + results);
            if (results == 1)
            {
                Application.Current.Properties["UpdatedData"] = miles;
                var nav = MyNavigation.GetNavigation();
                await nav.PushAsync(new ViewMileage());
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see from my code I have logging statements and they are never reached. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is the full xaml that contains the buttons

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:Validate="clr-namespace:MileageManagerForms.Validators"
         xmlns:ViewModel ="clr-namespace:MileageManagerForms.ViewModels"
         x:Class="MileageManagerForms.Views.EditMileage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModel:EditViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<Grid BackgroundColor="Purple">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="47"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="85"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="85"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Text="Edit Mileage" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="25" />
    </Frame>
    <DatePicker  x:Name="sDate" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" Date="{Binding SDate}" BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextColor="White"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding EntError}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Yellow" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />
    <Label Text="Miles:" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="9" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding EntMiles}" Keyboard="Numeric" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8" >
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <Validate:MaxLengthValidator  MaxLength="6"/>
            <Validate:DecimalValidator />
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Label Text="Gas:" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="12" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding EntGas}"  Keyboard="Numeric" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8" >
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <Validate:MaxLengthValidator  MaxLength="6"/>
            <Validate:DecimalValidator />
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Label Text="Cost:" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="9"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding EntCost}"  Keyboard="Numeric" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="8" >
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <Validate:MaxLengthValidator  MaxLength="7"/>
            <Validate:DecimalValidator />
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Label Text="Note:" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding EntNote}"  Keyboard="Default" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="8">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <Validate:MaxLengthValidator  MaxLength="20"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Entry Text="{Binding EntId}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="8" IsVisible="false"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModel:EditViewModel}}, Path=UpdateMileage}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" IsEnabled="True" Text="Update" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextColor="Black" Margin="4"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModel:EditViewModel}}, Path=Cancel}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Cancel" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextColor="Black" Margin="4"/>
</Grid>
```

As for the question about the binding in the view code behind, I have this;

```
BindingContext = new EditViewModel();
```

Comment: are they contained in a template?  if not, I don't see why you need such a complex binding expression

Comment: To add to Jason's comment, please show what those XAML lines are **inside of**. If their parent (or higher ancestor) is ListView.ItemTemplate or CollectionView.ItemTemplate or DataTemplate or other template, that is important to know. Also, I doubt very much that `AncestorType` is correct. The ancestor must be some `View` or `Layout`, NOT some `ViewModel`. If you look at your XAML, `RelativeSource` is tracing back through all the xaml elements that CONTAIN the button. Can you give a link to whatever example code you started from?

Comment: Add to question the line of code that sets view's `BindingContext`. In view's constructor do you have `BindingContext = new YourViewModel();`? Add to question the entire hierarchy of your xaml, down to those button lines. Show the declarations of all of its ancestors. Something like `<ContentPage ... x:Class="YourPageName"> <StackLayout> ... ` to `<Button ... />`. If the buttons are more deeply nested (indented), then there will be more ancestors to show. If they are inside an ItemTemplate, then it might be all the above followed by `<ListView ...><Item.Template><DataTemplate>...<Button ...>`.

Comment: based on the XAML you posted, the binding should be as simple as `{Binding UpdateMileage}`

Comment: That is the way I originally had it coded and it did not work. I also had the beginning part of the method of the code view model as follows,    
    public Command Cancel => new Command(async () =>
        {});
as opposed to the way the update shows now it was like the cancel here.

Comment: **1)** DON'T set the `BindingContext` in BOTH XAML and c#. Remove the XAML one.  **2)** The binding you show definitely won't work. Go back to the original, simple, binding. Its unclear what is causing the problem.  I recommend making a new page, with nothing except a stacklayout containing one button, the command, and a version of `UpdateMileageData` that does nothing but the logging statement. (Or set a breakpoint). Verify that works. Then add code to it until it stops working.